# how to use persistance DB connection in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, database-connection

For each request, django is creating a new DB connection even after setting CONN_MAX_AGE variable in my Django DB configuration

My configurations -
python3.5/Django2.05/mysql-5.6

This is my DB configurations -

```
 {'default': {
    'CONN_MAX_AGE': 500,
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'NAME': DB_NAME,
    'OPTIONS': {},
    'PASSWORD': 'root',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'TEST': {'CHARSET': None, 'COLLATION': None, 'MIRROR': None, 
    'NAME': None},
    'TIME_ZONE': None,
    'USER': 'root'}}
```

According to the doc: [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#persistent-connections), it should not create a new connection till the CONN_MAX_AGE expires.

I am checking by hitting a get request to custom view and checking connection object by adding this statement -

```
from django.db import connections  
print (connections.all())
```

Log shows a new connection object, like this -

```
[INFO 2018-12-04 23:00:08,472 basehttp] "GET /health_check/ HTTP/1.1" 200 96
[<django.db.backends.mysql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7f2c5fb1a0b8>]
[INFO 2018-12-04 23:00:09,017 basehttp] "GET /health_check/ HTTP/1.1" 200 96
[<django.db.backends.mysql.base.DatabaseWrapper object at 0x7f2c5fa88d30>]
```

Another observation is -
By logging inside -
local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py
get_new_connection() is being called for **every request**, which according to me should not happen.

If this interpretation of logging/debugging by object name is wrong, **then suggest how should I ensure that the DB conncetion doesn't get created on each request.**
PS, I am new to django

Comment: Note that it's one connection *per thread*. How many threads are used depends on your server and its approach to concurrency. Note that the Django development server, in particular, creates a new thread for every request, so persistent connections don't have any effect.

Comment: Just to elaborate my understanding here, 
While using a development server(django runserver), CONN_MAX_AGE doesn't effect due to reason mentioned by Kevin.
While trying to run django using gunicorn, it will create fixed number of threads, which will indeed take care about CONN_MAX_AGE.
For example, Gunicorn server with 9 workers, will create 9 DB connections which will persist till the CONN_MAX_AGE expires.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with Kevin's answer. If you run the Django Development Server with nothreading argument, then you'll see the same connection object on `connections.all()`.

```
python manage.py runserver --nothreading
```